# AWS - Step Function - Lamba Invoke - The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I am trying to make a simple step function workflow but something really, really strange is happening.

I am trying to chain a "putItem" inside a dynamoDB, with a basic lambda. I am quite literally following the documentation step by step, yet somehow I get this error:

```
{
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "error": "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
  "cause": "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda. (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: b90b985a-1aca-4c5c-a340-df9b3dcdfcf7; Proxy: null)"
}
```

As I said, I literally followed the documentations steps, in particular flagging **create role** for the lambda function at creation of the state machine.

This is the autogenerated code of the state machine:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "DynamoDB PutItem",
  "States": {
    "DynamoDB PutItem": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::dynamodb:putItem",
      "Parameters": {
        "TableName": "CustomerOrderTable",
        "Item": {
          "orderId": {
            "S.$": "$.orderId"
          },
          "customerId": {
            "S.$": "$.customerId"
          }
        }
      },
      "Next": "Lambda Invoke"
    },
    "Lambda Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:597598337678:function:Test:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something I need to change here? Or where could the problem be? I am really clueless.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: The IAM role's trust policy must specify the Lambda service principal (lambda.amazonaws.com) as a trusted service. But I don't see anything related to the IAM role or trust policy in your question.

Comment: Note that the error message has nothing to do with StepFunctions, it is purely between Lambda and IAM.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure the execution role you assign to your Lambda has a trust relationship with Lambda so that it can use the role. To do so, your trust relationship should look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get more information on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

If you are following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-lambda-state-machine.html) tutorial, it makes it clear that the role you create should be using the option that states **Create a new role with basic Lambda permissions.** which will create the trust relationship for you.

Comment: As I said, I am using the option **Create a new role with basic Lambda permissions**, but for some reason I get this error. That's why I'm so dumbfound

Answer (score -1):

The issue was the fact that I was using a test lambda that I created to which I granted only specific permissions.  Thus, always double and triple check permissions.